# Exception при get запросе Silverlight

Tags: c#, исключения

Подскажите, почему срабатывает Exception?

```
(SYstem.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebReqest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult     asyncResult) at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.    <EndGetResponse>b_9(Object sendState) at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
```

---

```
 _urlRequest = "http://localhost:3019/func.cshtml";
  HtmlPage.Document.SetProperty("title", "Silverlight запрос и получение xml данных ");

private void Button_ClickGraphAvto(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        divider = 20;
        HttpWebRequest ht = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(_urlRequest + "?req=avto");
        IAsyncResult result = ht.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(RespCallbackXml), ht);
    }

    private void RespCallbackXml(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest ht = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)ht.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);


            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            responseStream.Position = 0;

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            string strXml = sr.ReadToEnd();
            ShowString(strXml);

            ShowGraph(responseStream);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            ShowString(e.InnerException.ToString());
        }
}
```

Comment: Возможно, неверный формат передаваемых данных. Прогоните через отладчик, что он покажет?

Comment: А вы не предполагаете, что сервер таки-да вернул «Not Found»?